# How can I group by Taxonomy on Custom Post Type while filtering out based on custom Meta

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, loop, query

I hope I can explain this without being too confusing.

I have a site where I have a custom post type that has two custom hierarchical taxonomies ( categories ) and each post also has a meta filed allowing for a true or false.

- **Post 1**

  - Meta - True
  - custom_taxonomy 1 - A
  - custom_taxonomy 2 - 1
- **Post 2**

  - Meta - True
  - custom_taxonomy 1 - B
  - custom_taxonomy 2 - 2
- **Post 3**

  - Meta - False
  - custom_taxonomy 1 - B
  - custom_taxonomy 2 - 1

I have the query working that will show all posts and if custom_taxonomy 1 or custom_taxonomy 2 is selected then will show those or if both are selected.

If at some point Meta is True then a `meta_query` is added.

What has really stumped me is that I am now being asked to basically group the posts with its custom_taxonomy 1 heading then the posts.

- **custom_taxonomy 1 - A**

  - Post 1
- **custom_taxonomy 1 - B**

  - Post 2
  - Post 3

Am I better off reworking the object and looping over the posts to get each posts custom taxonomies so that I can manually loop over them?

The one potential issue I thought about was doing this manually means I might not have `$loop->the_post()` and some other WordPress methods won't be set.

I have been thinking about this for too long and can no longer see clearly.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had miss guided hope that I could use one query that would group the results but in the end, the solution is to look up all **custom_taxonomy 1** results passing the slug into the Post query and looping it.

Because of all the different combinations of filters, I had to create a query builder that dealt with this for me.

In principle, these solutions will work. [How to group by taxonomy on Custom Post Type archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271968/how-to-group-by-taxonomy-on-custom-post-type-archive)
[how to group custom post type posts by custom taxonomy terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12369/how-to-group-custom-post-type-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-terms)